# Laravel eloquent table relationship for sorting data

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to develop an e-commerce website in Laravel but I am having trouble with sorting the data of a category. I tried it through eloquent but unable to sort by price. I tell you my database table structure.

Table category

```
id | user_id | name | slug | description | timestamp
```

Table product

```
id | user_id | name | slug | content | tags | extras | feature_image | timstamp
```

Table category_product_relation

```
id | category_id | product_id | timestamp
```

Table product_price

```
id | product_id | price | tax | discount | quantity | timestamp
```

Now, I want to sort products of a category by price. Let me know if this db structure is good or not. If it is not good kindly guide me.

Comment: What have you tried so far in your relationships?  As far as code.

Comment: Your structure is fine. I'm not sure if putting the product price in a different table is necessary, but it is up to you.

The right Laravel convention, by the way, is category_product and not category_product_relation.

Comment: In your structure, a product can have multiple prices. Do you want to sort a product by its latest price?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes I want to sort particular category products by its price, I don't want to write any SQL query, I want to do it by eloquent.

Comment: Can a product have multiple prices?

Comment: 1) I would use the price, tax and discount as fields in the products table unless you really need a product to have more than one price;
2) when you said you don't want to do SQL...but are you okay to use the DB class?